# How do I interact with a console application from my Java app?

Tags: java, console, external

How do I invoke an external console application (it ask questions to the user) from my Java application? (I need to get the data results, user input, back from the invoked app.)

Comment: So you have an application that is *not* a console application, and you would like to launch a console window to get some input from the user, and then close that window? I'm assuming there is some reason that you cannot just make the entire application a console application.

Comment: @johusman: I don't think it matters whether the client app is console or not, it's a Java app. And then it definitely does not matter how the "server" app is implemented except that it runs in the console and writes to stdio. There can be many use cases for this such as bridging to a legacy app that has no published or documented APIs etc.

Answer (score 2):

Lot's of code snippets [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html)

**Example :**

```
import java.io.*;
public class CmdExec {
  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    String appCommand = "path/to/your/executable param1 param2 ...";
    try {
      String line;
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(appCommand);
      p.waitFor();
      System.out.println(p.exitValue());
    }
    catch (Exception err) {
      err.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```